# Multiple threads writing to same partition

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

Say that I have a AWS Glue job that looks like this:

```
import threading

def thread_worker(df, id):
    df.write.mode('overwrite') \
    .save('./output_{0}'.format(id))
    
def main():
    ...
    
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=thread_worker, args=(df, id) \
        for id in range(2)]
        
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

But instead of having 2 I have 60,000 and the output goes to a single partition in S3. so like:

```
import threading

def thread_worker(df, id):
    df.write.mode('overwrite') \
    .save('s3://bucket/partition_name=x/')
    
def main():
    ...
    
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=thread_worker, args=(df, id) \
        for id in range(60000)]
        
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

This will fail with different `FileNotFound` Java exceptions. Which is caused by what I have come to learn is the _temporary directory created in S3. Each thread needs to have its own if they all write to the same partition.

So, my questions are:

- Can i pass an argument somewhere on `df.write` to use a custom name that is not `_temporary`?
- We are talking about a lot of data here, so it's either threading or several hours for the data to load. Is there a way to safely implement threads here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `FileNotFound` Java exception happens because you are passing a partition name (folder-like structure) in `'s3://bucket/partition_name=x/'`

My suggestion would to use the `id` argument in the `thread_worker` function to create a filename convention like `filename-{id}.ext`, so your function would be modified like this:

```
def thread_worker(df, id):
df.write.mode('overwrite') \
.save('s3://bucket/partition_name/filename-{0}.ext'.format(id))
```

Optionally you could create a filename based on uuid, if you think there is a chance of the same name getting repeated.